# How to make a GUI to visually add Mattertags into a Matterport scene?

Tags: matterport

There are 2 examples in the [Matterport SDK for Embeds documentation](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/sdk_home.html) to show how to place Mattertags in a scene:

- The [Intersection Inspector](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/sdk_intersection_inspector.html) which only allows you to see coordinates for placing a Mattertag where the cursor is if you wait a little bit ... Not very user friendly, you need to copy the coordinates manually in your program.
- The [Transient Tags Editor](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/sdk_transient_tags_editor.html) which enable you to interactively place multiple Mattertags visually, edit them and then to extract them easily in a JSON file ...

I was wondering how to reproduce the [Transient Tags Editor](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/sdk_transient_tags_editor.html) visual UX as I would like to use it in an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Insert Mattertags into the model visually

The source code of the [app](https://rmauldin.github.io/matterport/transient-tag-editor/app/) of the [Transient Tags Editor](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/sdk_transient_tags_editor.html) is privately hosted on **github** (Maybe because it doesn't run perfectly on Firefox?), unlike the [source code](http://jsfiddle.net/guillermo_matterport/pftnhkuc) of the [Intersection Inspector](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/sdk_intersection_inspector.html) which is publicly hosted on **JSFiddle**.

But the user friendliness of the [Transient Tags Editor](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/sdk_transient_tags_editor.html) intrigued me and I wanted to understand the difference between the two tools Matterport SDK provides to find out Mattertags coordinates.

#### How the Intersection Inspector works

The [Intersection Inspector](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/sdk_intersection_inspector.html) uses a **timer** to display a button at the position of the [`Pointer`](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/docs/sdkbundle/reference/current/modules/camera.html) when the user does not move the pointer for more than one second. The user can then click the button to see the **Mattertag** coordinates and copy them manually ...

To achieve that, it needs the current [`Camera`](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/docs/sdkbundle/reference/current/modules/camera.html) position, which it obtains by observing the camera's [`pose`](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/docs/sdkbundle/reference/current/modules/camera.html#pose-1) property:

```
    var poseCache;
    mpSdk.Camera.pose.subscribe(function(pose) {
        poseCache = pose;
    });
```

Also, it needs the current [`Pointer`](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/docs/sdkbundle/reference/current/modules/camera.html) position, which it obtains by observing the pointer's [`intersection`](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/docs/sdkbundle/reference/current/modules/pointer.html#intersection-1) property:

```
    var intersectionCache;
    mpSdk.Pointer.intersection.subscribe(function(intersection) {
        intersectionCache = intersection;
        intersectionCache.time = new Date().getTime();
        button.style.display = 'none';
        buttonDisplayed = false;
    });
```

※ An `intersection` event is triggered the user moves the pointer, so we hide the button to make sure it is not displayed before the one second delay is over.

Then, a **timer** is set up using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to display the button at the right time:

```
    setInterval(() => {
        // ...
    }, 16);
```

In the timer callback, we check wether all the conditions to display the button are met ...

- First, check we have the information we need:

```
    setInterval(() => {
        if (!intersectionCache || !poseCache) {
            return;
        }
        // ...
    }, 16);
```

- Then, check one second has elapsed since the last `intersection` event was received, or we wait the next tick to check again:

```
    var delayBeforeShow = 1000;
    setInterval(() => {
        if (!intersectionCache || !poseCache) {
            return;
        }
        const nextShow = intersectionCache.time + delayBeforeShow;
        if (new Date().getTime() > nextShow) {
            // ...
        }
    }, 16);
```

- Finally, we check the button is not already being displayed:

```
    var delayBeforeShow = 1000;
    var buttonDisplayed = false;
    setInterval(() => {
        if (!intersectionCache || !poseCache) {
            return;
        }
        const nextShow = intersectionCache.time + delayBeforeShow;
        if (new Date().getTime() > nextShow) {
            if (buttonDisplayed) {
                return;
            }
            // ...
        }
    }, 16);
```

Once the conditions are met, we can display the button using [`Conversion.worldToScreen()`](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/docs/sdkbundle/reference/current/modules/conversion.html#worldtoscreen) to get the screen coordinate of the pointer :

```
    // ...
    setInterval(() => {
        // ...
        if (new Date().getTime() > nextShow) {
            // ...
            var size = {
                w: iframe.clientWidth,
                h: iframe.clientHeight,
            };
            var coord = mpSdk.Conversion.worldToScreen(intersectionCache.position, poseCache, size);
            button.style.left = `${coord.x - 25}px`;
            button.style.top = `${coord.y - 22}px`;
            button.style.display = 'block';
            buttonDisplayed = true;
        }
    }, 16);
```

The button is a simple HTML button hidden by default using `display: none;` and positioned relative to the body with `position: absolute;`.

When the user clicks the button, the current coordinates of the pointer are displayed in a `<div>` tag above the `<iframe>` and the button is hidden:

```
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        text.innerHTML = `position: ${pointToString(intersectionCache.position)}\nnormal: ${pointToString(intersectionCache.normal)}\nfloorId: ${intersectionCache.floorId}`;
        button.style.display = 'none';
        iframe.focus();
    });
```

The coordinates are formatted using the following function:

```
function pointToString(point) {
  var x = point.x.toFixed(3);
  var y = point.y.toFixed(3);
  var z = point.z.toFixed(3);

  return `{ x: ${x}, y: ${y}, z: ${z} }`;
}
```

Now, let's see how the easier-to-use and user-friendlier [Transient Tags Editor](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/sdk_transient_tags_editor.html) interface works ...

#### How the Transient Tag Editor works

The [Intersection Inspector](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/sdk_intersection_inspector.html) is enough if you just have a few __Mattertag__s to set permanently in a few models in your application. But if you need your users to set tags interactively in models, something like the [Transient Tags Editor](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/sdk_transient_tags_editor.html)'s GUI is a better starting point.

The main advantage of using the [Transient Tags Editor](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/sdk_transient_tags_editor.html) is that you can see how the `Mattertag` will be displayed before creating it and! That allows you to place the tag precisely without trial and error ...

To add a tag, you must click on the "Place New Tag" button to enter the "add tag" mode, then you can place one new tag anywhere you want.

We will only focus on that aspect of the editor and produce a simplified code sample that only add tags:

- As the user move a tag along the pointer when in "add tag" mode, the first step is to create a new tag and place it. Let's create a function for that  using [`Mattertag.add()`](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/docs/sdkbundle/reference/current/modules/mattertag.html#add):

```
    function addTag() {
        if(!tag){
            mpSdk.Mattertag.add([{
                label: "Matterport Tag",
                description: "",
                anchorPosition: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0},
                stemVector: {x:0, y: 0, z: 0},
                color: {r: 1, g: 0, b: 0},
            }])
            .then((sid) => {
                tag = sid[0];
            })
            .catch( (e) => {
                console.error(e);
            })
        }
    }
```

- Then we will have to place the tag at a position near the pointer, and update its position as the user moves the pointer, so let's create a function for that using [`Mattertag.editPosition()`](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/docs/sdkbundle/reference/current/modules/mattertag.html#editposition):

```
    function updateTagPos(newPos, newNorm=undefined, scale=undefined){
        if(!newPos) return;
        if(!scale) scale = .33;
        if(!newNorm) newNorm = {x: 0, y: 1, z: 0};

        mpSdk.Mattertag.editPosition(tag, {
            anchorPosition: newPos,
            stemVector: {
                x: scale * newNorm.x,
                y: scale * newNorm.y,
                z: scale * newNorm.z,
            }
        })
        .catch(e =>{
            console.error(e);
            tag = null;
        });
    }
```

As you can see the `updateTagPos()` function takes 3 parameters:

1. **newPos**: the new anchor position for the `Mattertag`.
2. **newNorm**: an optional new stem vector for the `Mattertag`.
3. **scale**: an optional new scale for the stem of the `Mattertag`.

- To update the tag position as the user moves the pointer, let's observe the pointer's [`intersection`](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/docs/sdkbundle/reference/current/modules/pointer.html#intersection-1) property to call `updateTagPos()`:

```
    mpSdk.Pointer.intersection.subscribe(intersectionData => {
        if(tag){
            if(intersectionData.object === 'intersectedobject.model' || intersectionData.object === 'intersectedobject.sweep'){
                updateTagPos(intersectionData.position, intersectionData.normal);
            }
        }
    });
```

- To place the new tag, the user simply clicks their mouse button, the [Transient Tags Editor](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/sdk_transient_tags_editor.html) provides its own version of the `document.activeElement` method for intercepting clicks on the `<iframe>` *(but does not work with **Firefox** so the editor use a quite complex workaround)*:

```
    function focusDetect(){
        const eventListener = window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
            if (document.activeElement === iframe) {
                placeTag(); //function you want to call on click
                setTimeout(function(){ window.focus(); }, 0);
            }
            window.removeEventListener('blur', eventListener );
        });
    }
```

But, we will use our version which works better with **Firefox** *(But still stop working after the first click in **Firefox** for whatever reason)*:

```
    window.addEventListener('blur',function(){  
        window.setTimeout(function () { 
            if (document.activeElement === iframe) {
                placeTag(); //function you want to call on click
                window.focus()
                addTag();
            }
        }, 0);
    });
```

- Finally, let's the function that navigates to the new tag and **opens its billboard**, using[`Mattertag.navigateToTag()`](https://matterport.github.io/showcase-sdk/docs/sdkbundle/reference/current/modules/mattertag.html#navigatetotag)

```
    function placeTag(){
        if(tag) mpSdk.Mattertag.navigateToTag(tag, mpSdk.Mattertag.Transition.INSTANT);
        tag = null;
    }
```

#### Simple Editor Code Sample

First, the complete JavaScript source code:

```
"use strict";

const sdkKey = "aaaaXaaaXaaaXaaaXaaaXaaa"
const modelSid = "iL4RdJqi2yK";

let iframe;
let tag;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    iframe = document.querySelector('.showcase');
    iframe.setAttribute('src', `https://my.matterport.com/show/?m=${modelSid}&help=0&play=1&qs=1&gt=0&hr=0`);
    iframe.addEventListener('load', () => showcaseLoader(iframe));
});

function showcaseLoader(iframe){
    try{
        window.MP_SDK.connect(iframe, sdkKey, '3.10')
        .then(loadedShowcaseHandler)
        .catch(console.error);
    } catch(e){
        console.error(e);
    }
}

function loadedShowcaseHandler(mpSdk){
    addTag()

    function placeTag(){
        if(tag) mpSdk.Mattertag.navigateToTag(tag, mpSdk.Mattertag.Transition.INSTANT);
        tag = null;
    }

    window.addEventListener('blur',function(){  
        window.setTimeout(function () { 
            if (document.activeElement === iframe) {
                placeTag(); //function you want to call on click
                window.focus()
                addTag();
            }
        }, 0);
    });
    function updateTagPos(newPos, newNorm=undefined, scale=undefined){
        if(!newPos) return;
        if(!scale) scale = .33;
        if(!newNorm) newNorm = {x: 0, y: 1, z: 0};

        mpSdk.Mattertag.editPosition(tag, {
            anchorPosition: newPos,
            stemVector: {
                x: scale * newNorm.x,
                y: scale * newNorm.y,
                z: scale * newNorm.z,
            }
        })
        .catch(e =>{
            console.error(e);
            tag = null;
        });
    }

    mpSdk.Pointer.intersection.subscribe(intersectionData => {
        if(tag){
            if(intersectionData.object === 'intersectedobject.model' || intersectionData.object === 'intersectedobject.sweep'){
                updateTagPos(intersectionData.position, intersectionData.normal);
            }
        }
    });

    function addTag() {
        if(!tag){
            mpSdk.Mattertag.add([{
                label: "Matterport Tag",
                description: "",
                anchorPosition: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0},
                stemVector: {x:0, y: 0, z: 0},
                color: {r: 1, g: 0, b: 0},
            }])
            .then((sid) => {
                tag = sid[0];
            })
            .catch( (e) => {
                console.error(e);
            })
        }
    }
} // loadedShowcaseHandler
```

The HTML source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Transient Tag Editor</title>
        <style>
            #showcase {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100vh;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://static.matterport.com/showcase-sdk/2.0.1-0-g64e7e88/sdk.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/app-editor.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="showcase" frameborder="0"  allowFullScreen allow="xr-spatial-tracking"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works!

### Complete Code

The complete code for this sample and others is available on **github**:
[github.com/loic-meister-guild/pj-matterport-sdk-2021-tutorial](https://github.com/loic-meister-guild/pj-matterport-sdk-2021-tutorial)

### See Also

- [Matterport SDK 2021 Tutorial](https://qiita.com/loic-meister-guild/items/8cf015969d9fbddc2160)
- [Node.js + Express Tutorial for 2021](https://catalins.tech/nodejs-express-tutorial-for-2021-getting-started-with-the-javascript-web-server-framework)
- [How to detect a click event on a cross domain iframe](https://gist.github.com/jaydson/1780598)